# AngularJS-Google-Places not returning details

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get google places details using [angularjs-google-places](https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-google-places) but all I get is an empty object. I have tried setting it up as demonstrated in the documentation but I still don't get any results. This [codepen](http://codepen.io/mobvino/pen/LEbvPr) is from someone else but shows exactly what I am getting. Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularjs-google-places/dist/angularjs-google-places.min.js"></script>
...
```

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('cityApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap',
    'ngCordova',
    'ngGPlaces'
  ]) 

    ...
```

**restaurants.js**

```
angular.module('cityApp')
  .controller('RestaurantsCtrl', function ($scope, ngGPlacesAPI) {
    $scope.details = ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({reference:"ChIJ4yo36JUn5IgRXgiRD7KMDe0"}).then(function (data) {
      return data;
    });
  });
```

**restaurants.html**

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <p>{{details}}</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to that codepen, the data is actually coming through because if you `console.log()` it, you can see the data. The way they are displaying the data is the issue. The return doesn't work. You have to set `$scope.details = data`

Comment: Interesting!  The example on GitHub definitely says to use the return, but that codepen is definitely not working with the return.  Its also worth noting I think that its also the case that the OPs reference string is invalid (as mentioned in the other answer.  Putting that string into the codepen it doesnt even get to the .then

Comment: yeah I saw the string and I agree, It doesn't look right. I haven't had luck with a return when using it this way which is why I usually use a service. If anyone wants to chime in on why the return doesn't work, that'd be helpful

Comment: This works in addition to changing the reference. Thank you! The place id i used came from googles placeID finder though, so now I don't know where to find the right placeid

Comment: just realized reference and placeId are 2 separate things so changing `reference:'******'` to `placeId:'*******'` fixed it to let me use a placeId instead of a reference

Answer (score 0):

Your reference is wrong.
try a good one and it will work.

try this example:

```
$scope.details = ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({reference:"CnRnAAAAnRm_imIW_SFd74bsj6iRwvRxBamZqtUaSyRjlb-i1vvkapOSVXyA5Dj452GSpBpno_MHbxyGsuFx9zqZvr_aa2a7uG0IZE8tC-N2OccvUC_i5N3QRQ11WmSRayo441riHebwQGqlbaf3RY-5KVsfGBIQXGtmUICHsD9LH2rd_y-J2hoUvW0lUEIHHtRnD15QyeUqi6tkHIg"}).then(function (data) {
    return data;
  });
```